# groupBy, filter and memory leak in Rx

Tags: java, memory-leaks, reactive-programming, rx-java, reactivex

According to the documentation of `groupBy`:

> Note: A `GroupedObservable` will cache the items it is to emit until such time as it is subscribed to. For this reason, in order to avoid memory leaks, you should not simply ignore those `GroupedObservable`s that do not concern you. Instead, you can signal to them that they may discard their buffers by applying an operator like `take(int)(0)` to them.

There's a [RxJava tutorial](https://github.com/Froussios/Intro-To-RxJava) which says:

> Internally, every Rx operator does 3 things
>
> 1. It subscribes to the source and observes the values.
> 2. It transforms the observed sequence according to the operator's purpose.
> 3. It pushes the modified sequence to its own subscribers, by calling onNext, onError and onCompleted.

Let's take a look at the following code block which extracts only even numbers from `range(0, 10)`:

```
Observable.range(0, 10)
        .groupBy(i -> i % 2)
        .filter(g -> g.getKey() % 2 == 0)
        .flatMap(g -> g)
        .subscribe(System.out::println, Throwable::printStackTrace);
```

My questions are:

1. Does it mean `filter` operator already implies a subscription to every group resulted from `groupBy` or just the `Observable<GroupedObservable>` one?
2. Will there be a memory leak in this case? If so,
3. How to properly discard those groups? Replace `filter` with a custom one, which does a `take(0)` followed by a `return Observable.empty()`? You may ask why I don't just return `take(0)` directly: it's because `filter` doesn't neccessarily follow right after `groupBy`, but can be anywhere in the chain and involve more complex conditions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your suspicions are correct in that to properly handle the grouped observable each of the inner observables (`g`) must be subscribed to. As `filter` is subscribing to the outer observable only it's a bad idea. Just do what you need in the `flatMap` using `ignoreElements` to filter out undesired groups.

```
Observable.range(0, 10)
    .groupBy(i -> i % 2)
    .flatMap(g -> {
       if (g.getKey() % 2 == 0) 
         return g;
       else 
         return g.ignoreElements();
    })
    .subscribe(System.out::println, Throwable::printStackTrace);
```

Comment: adjusted this answer to incorporate the suggestion from @akarnokd about ignoreElements.

Comment: This code is not compiling, because `g.ignoreElements()` returns a `Completable`. Any thoughts on how to deal with this?

Comment: Figured it out. Just `return g.ignoreElements().toObservable();`

Answer (score 5):

Apart from the memory leak, the current implementation may end up hanging completely due to internal request coordination problems.

Note that using `take(0)`, the group may be recreated all the time. I'd instead use `ignoreElements` which drops values, no items reach `flatMap` and the group itself won't be recreated all the time.

Comment: What am I missing here, but if I do exactly what the docs advise against and ignore/discard all references, then the grouped observables will become subject to garbage collection; including their buffers?

I understand that upstream observables may keep a reference to downstream observers, but in the example posted no reference to the upstream observable was saved and as long as the developer are in control of both and makes sure to not save any references at all, then we're safe?

Otherwise, does the posted example and accepted answer suggest that filters can not be used with groups?